# my layout won't layout right

Tags: android

I have a TableLayout that won't behave and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong or not doing right

[image: my person icon I want much larger]

Here is my layout file

```
<TableLayout 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:background="@drawable/wall_paper"

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <TableRow 
     android:layout_weight="1"
     android:paddingTop="25dp">
  <LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="@string/name" 
        android:textColor="@color/nb_text"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"/>
    <EditText android:id="@+id/name" 
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
  </LinearLayout>
</TableRow>

<TableRow android:layout_weight="1">
  <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <Button android:id="@+id/chgPhoto" 
        android:text="@string/newphoto" 
        android:background="@drawable/camera"
        android:layout_height="40dp" 
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dip" 
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:gravity="left"          ></Button>
    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/StuPhoto" 
        android:src="@drawable/person_icon"
        android:layout_width="100dip" 
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dip" ></ImageView>
  </LinearLayout>
</TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

I want the person icon and resulting photo to be much bigger and shifted farther to the right but nothing I do seems to help. In fact, when I increase the layout_width/height of the photo, it simply shifts the icon with that space like so:

[image: larger dimensions means shifted down and right]

Any ideas on how to make this behave? Be kind - I readily admit layouts have me confused.

Answer (score 0):

try adding stretchColumns="*" to your tablelayout and why don't you set a layout_gravity for the picture you're trying to move to the right?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up going the opposite route with this - rather than scale the drawables, which maybe of various sizes, to the layout I want, I went to the images themselves and scaled them to what I want.
Then I can use "wrap_parent" or whatever without having to scale the image. Seems a hard way to go
as I might want larger or smaller drawbles on another device. But specifying the size jacked things up to no end